# How to export a data frame in R to a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, create-table

I tried `sqlSave()` in RODBC, but it runs super slowly. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could look at the package `RMySQL`. I am using it and it offers quite some convenience loading and reading data from a MySQL database. That being said it is limited in the queries you can use (e.g. HAVING is not possible IIRC). I can't say it's super-quick or my data is that big, but it's several 2-digits MB of text and it's ok. Depends on what you expect. However it's convenient:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="pass", 
    dbname="mydb", host="localhost",client.flag=CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)

dbListTables(con)
yourtable <- dbReadTable(con,"sometable")
# write it back
dbWriteTable(con,"yourTableinMySQL",yourtable,overwrite=T)
# watch out with the overwrite argument it does what it says :)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

`yourtable` will be a data.frame. Sometimes it bugs me that the modes are not set like i'd expect, but I have a custom made function for that. Just need to improve it then I'll post it here.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/

Comment: Hello, I have issues installing RMySQL. Can anyone show me the right way to install it?

Comment: "issues" is difficult to assess. Is MySQL running correctly? is the compilation of the R package the problem? What OS are you running? What error message do you get? I see that there is NO binary for windows. That means you got to download the source and compile on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have mysql client codes installed before you try installing RMySQL. Without knowing what OS and version you use it is really not possible to give any better answer.